# AsyncFileUpload Causing postback in UpdatePanel in User Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asyncfileupload

I have found many occurrences of similar questions but none with a solution.

I have an asyncfileupload in an update panel on a usercontrol.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload ID="AFU1" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="FileUploadComplete" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I also have a public string on this user control.

```
Public connum as string
```

when the usercontrol is loaded the connum is populated. For example.

```
usercontrol1.connum = "200001"
```

My code for the onloadedcomplete event is as follows.

```
    Public Sub FileUploadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim FilePath As String = "\\ukwilv-as3\Aspray\" '+ connum + "\"
        Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AFU1.FileName)
        AFU1.SaveAs(FilePath + filename)
        MsgBox(connum)
End Sub
```

As you can see from my code i want to include the connum in my filepath but after uploading the image connum has cleared. = "" i have confirmed this by adding the

```
msgbox(connum)
```

This just loads an empty message box.

From reading online many places say asyncfileupload does not cause postback however this cannot be the case if my string on this usercontrol is being reset to "" on uploading a file.

Any help would be very much appreciated as i have spent hours and hours googling this.

Thank you in advance.